# Setup RHEL/CentOS 5 to use SUDO in command line and X

Tags: linux, authentication, redhat, sudo

How do I make CentOS/RHEL prompt me for *my* password (and not roots) when I run a privileged   command.  I have found many guides that detail how to do this for the command line but I want it to work for X windows applications as well.

Or in other words: How do I make RHEL/CentOS behave like Ubuntu.

Comment: It sounds more like you wanted to add this to the CentOS wiki instead of posting it as a question here...

Comment: This would make a really great *answer* to a question...

Comment: Also a great community wiki, which I can not set.  I am sorry you couldn't answer it to gain points, but adding knowledge to serverfault was my primary goal.

Comment: Wanting to add info here is fine, but you really should take the time to follow the site format.  That is ask a question how to do X, and then provide an answer telling us how to do X.  Then you can accept your own answer.  Heck, maybe someone might even suggest some alternative answers to accomplish the same thing using a different method.

Comment: Yeah, why not edit your question to a question. Then post the above as an answer and accept it. No one will have a problem with that. I've done it quite a few times because after asking a question, that no one could answer, I've found the answer myself.

Comment: @ErebusBat Could you please copy the text to an answer and leave only the question part (first paragraph)?

Comment: I will do that,  I just thought that would be disingenuous where I already had the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Terminal Setup

As root, we need to edit the `/etc/sudoers` file by running `visudo` (NOTE: You can `export EDITOR=vim` to get syntax highlighting, or use the editor of your choice).
Around lines 83,86 you should see two lines that are similar (in vim you can run `:set number` to show line numbers):

```
83 # %wheel  ALL=(ALL)       ALL
84
85 ## Same thing without a password
86 # %wheel  ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL
```

The difference is that line #83 will require the user to enter **their** password to authenticate, whereas line #86 will allow the user to `sudo` without re-prompting them for their password.  Best security practices state that #83 is more secure; however depending on your situation #86 can be appropriate (for example I generally use #86 while setting up a server then switch to #83).

Exit and save that file.

Now we need to tell the system which users are allowed to escalate their permissions via `sudo`.  This is done by adding them to the `wheel` group, that is what the `%wheel` indicated in the `sudoers` file we edited earlier.  See `man sudoers` for more information on that file format.

```
$ usermod -a -G wheel erebusbat
```

That command will add the user `erebusbat` to the wheel group, combined with our earlier change would all them to run any command as root:

```
erebusbat@centos$ sudo whoami
root
erebusbat@centos$
```

## X / GNOME Setup

In CentOS/RHEL 5 and below the X authentication is handled by a set of programs called `consolehelper` and `userhelper`.  Basically what happens is this:  when a user executes a program (say `pirut`) it checks to see if there is a files called `pirut` in the folder `/etc/security/console.apps/` if we look at one of those files it looks like:

```
USER=root
PROGRAM=/usr/sbin/pirut
SESSION=true
KEEP_ENV_VARS=http_proxy,ftp_proxy
```

This tells `consolehelper`/`userhelper` to allow the user to authenticate and run the program as root.  If we `man userhelper` we see that we can add a `UGROUPS=` directive so that if a user were in that group they would be allowed to authenticate as themselves, but run the application as the user specified in the `USER=` directive.  So out `pirut` file needs to look like:

```
USER=root
UGROUPS=wheel
PROGRAM=/usr/sbin/pirut
SESSION=true
KEEP_ENV_VARS=http_proxy,ftp_proxy
```

As soon as we make that change whenever we attempt to run `pirut` as a normal user (Add/Remove Programs from the GNOME Menu) one of two things will happen:

1. We will be prompted for OUR password and the program will launch as `root`.
2. We will be prompted for `root`'s password if the current user is not in the `wheel` group.

However changing all those files by hand can be a PIA, so we work smarted and not harder:

```
$ cd /etc/security/console.apps/
$ sudo su -
$ pcregrep -ML '^UGROUPS=' * | xargs sed -i 's/^USER=root/USER=root\nUGROUPS=wheel/'
```

The `sudo su -` command is not needed if you are currently `root`.  The command will not 'double fix' any file so it can be `chron`ed or set to run on startup to make sure your files are ok.  Updates and installs can overwrite them or create new ones that do not have the `UGROUPS=` directive.

## Disabling root User

Once that is all setup and tested you should disable the root user:

```
$ sudo passwd -l root
```

That is a lowercase L, as in LOCK.

Then you should set or change `PermitRootLogin no` in your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file.  This is useful even if you lock the root account, in case anyone enables it in the future. `sudo su -` will still work even if you set this, see below, so there really is no reason to not set it.

If you decide to not lock the root account it is not ideal as anyone can login to the text/X/GNOME console as `root` and that is when bad things happen (the console stays logged in or you accidentaly delete a bunch of OS files [ask me how I know], best to lock the account.

## Running as root for extended periods

Sometimes, such as software installs, it is necessary to run many commands as `root` and not desirable to have to prefix each with `sudo`.  You have two options in this case:

1. Temporarily switch to the `root` account: `$ sudo su -`  That command will give you the same command shell as if you had logged into the account as root.
2. Unlock the root account: `$ sudo passwd root` This will allow you to set a password and  unlock the account; however **it is not temporary** and you must remember to lock the user account after you are done.

Comment: Now that is one classy answer.  I pursued this path myself a few months ago and got as far as the `consolehelper` tool.  After that, all I could see was a dead end.  You have presented an extremely elegant solution, especially the UGROUPS part.  Thanks!